# Creating a service worker that can run in background, using signalr for asp.net site

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, push-notification, signalr

I'm playing with different ways to create push notifications in asp.net core, since my boss asked me to research it.

So i just set up a barebones project that uses signalr to send messages from a hub to the client, and conversely for the client to the hub.

Currently, I have a button on a certain page where this javascript is used:

```
function receive() {
    $.ajax({
        url: '/msg/SendToClient',
        type: 'get',
    });
}

var connection = new signalR.HubConnectionBuilder()
    .withUrl("/NotificationHub")
    .build();
connection.on("ReceiveMessage", function (user, message) {
    alert(message);
});
connection.start();
```

Where the `receive()` is called everytime the button is pushed, that means that a corresponding controller action is called, which sends a message from server -> client.

But what I want is that I would like the javascript file to be laying on the client, and just run once in a while to check for new available push notifications.
A few scenarios are available, and I would like to know about all of them:

- Push notifications when browser is closed. I'm guessing this is not possible with a "regular" service worker?
- Push notification when browser is open, but site is not open. For this, I guess I will need to somehow have a javascript file/service worker on the clients computer just always running. This I really have no idea how to achieve this.
- A push notification that can work when the site is open in the browser. All I think I need for this is to have the javascript included always when the user is on the site, and then somehow make a request every few minutes.

Any inputs on these three things will be greatly appreciated. Is any of them easily achieveable/advisable? Is there any "normal" mode of operation for these three approaches to push notifications?
For any of these three scenarios, is there a case where signalr is parhaps not the best resource?

Comment: _Push notification when browser is open, but site is not open._: You need a PWA + Service Worker. See: https://blog.elmah.io/how-to-send-push-notifications-to-a-browser-in-asp-net-core/

Comment: "somehow make a request every few minutes" - why? With SignalR, they're *push* notifications. Making a request at intervals would be known as polling, which is the opposite of pushing. With a push notifications, you maintain an active connection, and the server sends (pushes) a message to the clients when there's something new they need to care about. The only time you would send a request for items is if you lost connectivity - you'd want to ask the server what you missed while connectivity is down.

Comment: @mason, perhaps using the term "make a request" was unclear. Having the server push the notifications would work just as well. My issue is with how I can achieve this. If the user is browsing around the site, how can I have a javascript file running that is constantly waiting to receive something from the server?

Comment: @abdusco currently it's a pretty vanilla asp.net core site, and not an app. is there any way that I can integrate the approach for making push notifications for a pwa, in my "regular" site?

Comment: PWA and ASP.NET Core are not mutually exclusive. You can put PWA features on top of whatever HTML you write. Then you can register a service worker, get permission from the user, declare your app as PWA so that it can be installed and so on. See: https://web.dev/push-notifications-overview/

Comment: The article uses some API that I am having a really hard deciphering what is. It has something to do with mozilla, but other than that the info about it is super sparse